# How can I create an editable select control (dropdown the user can add new values to)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to display a dropdown in a lightning component, but I also want the user to be able to add items to it. So far I'm not seeing this ability in either the ui:inputSelect or the lightning:select. Any advice?

Comment: Please visit - [Ask] and narrow your question as well as include what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ui:inputSelect` and set the `options` attribute. When this attribute is set, the input will automatically update the list with the new options.

You can see an example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputSelect.htm) under the "Generating Options Dynamically" section. In this example they set the `options` attribute in the init handler like so:

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp) {
        var opts = [
            { class: "optionClass", label: "Option1", value: "opt1", selected: "true" },
            { class: "optionClass", label: "Option2", value: "opt2" },
            { class: "optionClass", label: "Option3", value: "opt3" }

        ];
        cmp.find("InputSelectDynamic").set("v.options", opts);
    }
})
```

For your case, instead of setting `options` in the init handler you can get, modify, and re-set the `options` attribute based on user input.